# how to add gui function and inputs to js node server?

Tags: node.js

I currently have a server running in node on my pc. there are many variables that change as the server is accessed by internet users. of course I do have the console log to push some relevant stuff, but was wondering if it is possible in node to code some sort of gui or local display on my server machine for myself as the administrator while it is running? My intention after that would be to access either keyboard strokes or mouse inputs with node to interact with my server and current variables locally without the console log.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js has a beutifical feature called REPL.  so technically you can develop a GUI  PC app ,or web app to interact with node on different port then its serves client.  e.g there is this module called  [node-web-repl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-web-repl)
You can study how to develop REPL client. or dig out more open source may be by searching node REPL on google.

Comment: seems this should be a good solution for me to look into. Thanks!